# selecting value from previous table, incrementing it and inserting it into the new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm a newbie doing this project for my academics. I have an identity column  `slno`.
I need to select the `EmpID` from the previous row and increment it by 1 and add it to the new row with the below things. but i don't have any idea how to achieve this.

P.S: I've commented the EmpID string format.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Emplo ([Name],[Password],[Designation],[Dept],[D O B],[Sex],[Address]) values (@Name,@pass,@des,@dept,@DOB,@Sex,@Address)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@des", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dept", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RadioButton1.SelectedItem.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CreateRandomPassword(6);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Registered successfully......!')</script>");
    }
    //String result = String.Format("a{0:0000}", i);
    //Response.Write("<script>alert('Your Employee ID is  " + Server.HtmlEncode(result.ToString()) + "')</script>");
con.Close();
}
```

Comment: just put autoincreament of your `EmpId` true by 1 at database level

Comment: the format should be like a00001 so i can't use auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i used! I've no idea about sql stored procedure, so i can't tell whether the answer given by @zohar peled is correct or not.
below is the code which i used to fetch the previous row value(alphanumeric) and increment it by 1
`using (SqlCommand cnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 EmpId FROM Emplo ORDER BY EmpId DESC", con))
        {
            string x =Convert.ToString(cnd.ExecuteScalar());
            string justNumbers = new String(x.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(justNumbers);
            numbers = numbers + 1;
            resul = string.Format("a{0:0000}", numbers);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Your Employee ID is " + Server.HtmlEncode(resul) + "')</script>");//to display generated EmpID
        }`
resul is declared globally so that i can use it in insert statement.
add what ever the alphabet you need in the place of 'a'

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with c#, nor does it have anything to do with MySql at least based on your code, you are using SQL Server and not MySql.
You can set the EmpId as an identity column.

After our conversation in the comments I went back to SQL Fiddle and played around for 3 minutes, came up with this:

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    EmpId int IDENTITY(1,1),
    EmpName char(3)
)
```

Insert sample data

```
INSERT INTO T(EmpName) VALUES ('abc'), ('def'), ('ghi')
```

Format EmpId in Select:

```
SELECT EmpId, 
       EmpName, 
       RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 5) + CAST(EmpId as varchar(5)), 5) As FormattedEmpId
FROM T;
```

Using Formatted EmpId in Where:

```
DECLARE @EmpId nvarchar(5)
SET @EmpId = '00002'

SELECT EmpId, EmpName
FROM T
WHERE EmpId = CAST(@EmpId as int)
```

As you can see, EmpId is stored as an int identity column, and you can manipulate it in pure t-sql in the select clause to make it look like it has leading zeros, and and the where clause to cast a string with leading zeros to a simple int value.

I would suggest formatting the EmpId in the c# software you are writing, since display issues is not the database's job, but as you can see it is absolutely possible.

Check it out live here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9819/11

Comment: EmpID's format should be like a00001, a00002 ...... so i can't use identity column

Comment: Why not? Format can be manipulated outside of the table, even outside of the sql server. There is no reason to create your own identity mechanism just for format.

Comment: i need to because these ID'd are used to login

Comment: Again, format can be manipudated outside of the sql server. I see you are using c#, it's very easy to add / remove leading zeroes in the c#. deffinatly easier then creating your own identity function in sql, and will have better performance as well.

Comment: See the following sql fiddle as an example on how to format an identity column the way you want it in pure t-sql:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9819/4